# Using White/UIAutomation How to get a right-click context menu

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

When using UIAutomation I can't seem to be able to get a reference to the context menu that is shown when a right click is command is executed.

The following example shows a case where I opened up a new window with a (windows explorer inside it),got its correct reference from the available DesktopWindows (note that I can move it ok) and triggered the context menu via a right-click.

```
var windowName = "This is a WinForms window: {0}".format(3.randomLetters());
var topPanel = O2Gui.open<Panel>(windowName,600,200 );
var webBrowser = topPanel.add_WebBrowser_Control();

webBrowser.open("".o2Temp2Dir());
var guiAutomation = new API_GuiAutomation();
var window = guiAutomation.desktopWindow(windowName);
window.move(0,0);
window.mouse_MoveTo();
guiAutomation.mouse().rightClick(); 

window.infoTypeName();
return window.Popup;

//O2File:API_GuiAutomation.cs
//O2Ref:White.Core.dll 
//O2Ref:UIAutomationClient.dll
```

I tried to use the window.Popup variable to get the popup but that was null (not that the window object is of type White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.WinFormWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you answered your own question here: http://white.codeplex.com/discussions/250129
;)

**EDIT: I found a way to do this:**

```
public static PopUpMenu getContextMenu(this API_GuiAutomation guiAutomation)     
    {
        try
        {
            var emptyWindow = guiAutomation.desktopWindow("");
            return emptyWindow.Popup;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

which can then be consumed like this:

```
    var contextMenu =  guiAutomation.getContextMenu();
    contextMenu.menu("Git Clone...").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static PopUpMenu GetCurrentPopUpMenu(){

    List<Window> windows = WindowFactory.Desktop.DesktopWindows();
    foreach(Window w in windows)
    {
        if(w.Name == "") return w.PopUp;
    }
    return null;
}
```